# Cross Platform Python GUI Application

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

Using python I am going to develop a cross-platform GUI application with following constraints

- Support all platform
- Desktop application with one click installation
- Also, have a tool for creating GUI (Drag and Drop)

Can some guide me to find out best python modules or packages to satisfy all my constraints

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Really wanna flag this. But I'll answer:

Q: Support all platforms
A: *[tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)*

Q: Desktop app with one-click   installation
A: *[Pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io)* for EXE, *[NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net)* for installer

Q: Drag n' Drop?
A: [tkinter.dnd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

Q: DnD editor?
A: *PAGE*

Comment: For the third part - DnD - I think the OP is looking for a GUI builder, not the ability to add DnD to their app.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy and PyQt are both very powerful and well documented (especially PyQt), cross-platfrom GUI frameworks for python. Designers are available for both frameworks.

- https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro
- https://kivy.org/#home
- https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to GUI in python, I suggest you learn [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). It works on all platform assuming it runs python and have the module Tkinter in the python library. But I suggest you also read through this list to find what is suitable for your need. [GuiProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for Python.